# error with if else in html in django application

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement

Good afternoon, i have django application where i have issue

on main page there is header in base html, there is 1 button, but with 2 different values as link

```
                {% if roleworker %}
                    <li><a href="/addservice/">Add</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/addpage/">Add</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
```

roleworker is value in database, here is model for it

```
class Role(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Пользователь')
    roleworker = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

when user opens index.html it equals True, when user opens indexworker.html(here is posts from worker) it equal false, i checked that functionality of value in db for user, it works good

when user open some other page it must remember his value, for that there is that django model

this is function that check value of roleworker for user

```
def rolecheck(request, render):
    user = request.user
    role = Role.objects.get(user=user)
    roleworker = role.roleworker
    if roleworker == True:
        print('True')
    elif roleworker == False:
        print('False')
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'roleworker': roleworker})
```

but on html there is always "{% if roleworker %}" (it means == True)
even when in django admin it equal False

```
                {% if roleworker %}
                    <li><a href="/addservice/">Добавить (услуга)</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/addpage/">Добавить (статья)</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
```

Maybe someone know how to fix it, i will be very grateful if someone can help me, thanks for every one for reading it

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change it to the following:

```
def rolecheck(request, render):
    user = request.user
    role = Role.objects.get(user=user)

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'role': role})
```

And do this in your template:

```
                  {% if role.roleworker %}
                    <li><a href="/addservice/">Добавить (услуга)</a></li>
                  {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/addpage/">Добавить (статья)</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
```

Also try to use `{% url 'add-service' %}` instead of hardcoding urls, this will automatically link to the url with the name `add-service` which you can define in your `urls.py`